# Livewire error with multiple image upload, over 20 files

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am trying to upload mutliple images with Livewire and using Temporary Preview.

When I select up to 20 images, everything works fine. When I select 21 or more I get an error

"Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
value UploadManager.js:115
UploadManager.js:115:67"

The form I am using is

```
    <form wire:submit.prevent="uploadImages">

            <input type="file" wire:model="uploadImages" multiple>

            <x-admin.form.button class="bg-blue-450 text-white">
                Upload
            </x-admin.form.button>

            <div class="mt-4">
                @error('uploadImages.*')
                    <x-admin.alerts.flash type="error" class="mb-4">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </x-admin.alerts.flash>
                @enderror
                @error('uploadImages')
                    <x-admin.alerts.flash type="error" class="mb-4">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </x-admin.alerts.flash>
                @enderror
            </div>
            @if($uploadImages)
                <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                    @foreach ($uploadImages as $upload)
                        <img src="{{ $upload->temporaryUrl() }}" alt="" class="w-1/12 p-2 object-cover">
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that although the error points to JavaScript, the problem comes from the server.
I edited php.ini and changed max_file_uploads to 30 and everything works fine
I guess this happened with Livewire because it instantly uploads files to a temporary folder.